# Tuleap - how to turn on mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, tuleap

I'm running Tuleap™ 9.16.99.13. I see in the Tuleap Wiki documentation that MediaWiki is now available. Is there some way to turn on or activate MediaWiki or will that require upgrading?
[image]

Comment: Can someone with some experience with Tuleap please point me in the right direction for this question? If my question is not clear, please ask a question so that I can make it more clear. Really need to have mediaWiki turned on for my project.

Answer (score 1):

Mediawiki is a Tuleap plugin , you need to install it as site admin :
administration >> manage all plugins >> available plugins and click on install.
After this, you need to activate on your project. As project admin go on :
Youre project >> admin >> Services and enable it.

FYI Tuleap 9.16 is now an old version, some change have been made since.